# How many White Walkers are there?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

Throughout *Game of Thrones*, we have seen multiple [White Walkers](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/White_Walkers) die. As far as I remember:

- Sam killed one with dragonglass.
- Jon Snow killed one with Longclaw.
- Meera Reed killed one with a spearhead made of dragonglass.

So are there a set number of White Walkers that were created by the [Children of the Forest](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Forest)? If so, about how many are there?

**OR**

Can the [Night King](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Night_King) just create as many as he wants?

Comment: If the Night King has been around for 8,000 years, then there's no telling how many children he's turned. There's no reason to believe that he can only make White Walkers out of Craster's kids.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update as of Season 7, Episode 7.**

> There are **hundreds**!

The official script for Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf", has been released because it is up for an Emmy.

> [EXT. EASTWATCH, NORTH SIDE OF THE WALL]
>  
> Emerging from the frozen coastal forest, the ARMY OF THE DEAD comes in force. All of them, 100,000 strong, with **hundreds of WHITE WALKER officer corps** on their dead horses.

---

**Original Answer**

Yes, the Night's King can create more, as seen in S4E4

Since this is a living human being turned, it becomes a White Walker. The Wights are reanimated from those already dead.

The problem with this now is that it seems the source for these babies was Craster (who before that we are unsure). Since Craster is dead now it might a be bit harder to come across a steady supply of living human baby boys.

Comment: That's right. Sorry, I totally forgot about this scene. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: We should note that this is a serious bottleneck. This requires living human children, which are not easy to come by in a freezing forest (at least not after the shit that the Night's King pulled at Hardhome).

Comment: @goelakash Possibly. We don't know that they need to be children, and we don't know if the Hardhome children would have worked anyway. There are some that theorize that the bloodline of the person being turned into an Other matters.

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if being an *other* required you to be your grandfather's son.

Comment: @goelakash there are theories that ALL Others have Stark or Bolton blood. That's all I was referring to.

Comment: @kuhl Most have Craster blood I would think... is Craster decended from the Starks or Boltons? Yes the OG Night King was probably a Stark.

Comment: @Skooba it's a fan theory. Just saying there's a possibility that the hardhome people wouldn't have worked regardless.

Comment: Does that mean that there won't be any new White Walkers, now that the lands beyond the wall are deserted?

Comment: I would logically assume so.

Comment: You have to edit in another week :p