# How many White Walkers are out there?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones S07E06 when Jon and his group have a standoff with White Walkers we see a few White Walkers (4-6) along with the Night King.

Are they all the White Walkers in the world? Are some of them in some other place? If so, where?

Comment: Already answered over on SF & F - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91722/just-how-many-white-walkers-are-there

Comment: Also related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53454/how-many-white-walkers-are-there?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure...

[image: Knight's King Being Made]

The problem lies in that we have to assume that many of the White Walkers including the Night's King were made from The Children of the Forest changing men into them after a betrayal.

**Samwell Tarly:** *"The White Walkers sleep beneath the ice for thousands of years."*

And I don't recall if the books ever disclose how many, but even if they do, there was already an epic battle during the Age of Heroes/The Long Night and so we don't know how many were lost, just that the WW were temporarily defeated and somehow encased under ice...

[image: Knights King Changes Bay]

The TV series shows us that they take Craster's baby "boys" and The Knight's King seems to be able to "change" them--but it's unclear if they "evolve" or how fast they evolve verses if they just remain White Walkers in "baby" form? But if so, then there should be quite a few children-boys and young male Walkers when you consider how many children and how long Craster has been reproducing...

Comment: Why is `"boys"` enclosed in [scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes)?

Comment: @GhotiandChips think answer author meant it as "males, not females".

Comment: @ShadowWizard Maybe read my comment - it asks why it's enclosed in scare quotes. Your reply doesn't do anything in the realm of providing insight.

Comment: Because that of which I am referring would be an equivalent of boy-wights (babies/children/young adults) and I used those quotes to highlight the fact that Craster only gave boys and white walkers have all been male (or made from males) so far, because it's a curious point of interest.